# How to detect web3 of mobile wallets?

Tags: web3js, react, mobile-wallet

I am working on a react application and just can't catch the web3 object of mobile wallets. Catching web3 in Metamask works like a charm.

Here's my code so far:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
      let web3 = window.web3;
      if (web3) {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        web3.eth.getAccounts().then(accts => {
          web3.eth.net.getNetworkType().then(network => {
            this.setState({
              web3,
              isConnected: true,
              network: network,
              user: accts[0]
            });
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

So far I've tried Trust Wallet and Status Wallet and none of both works with the existing code.

I have also tried to user `web3.currentProvider.isTrust` but that doesn't seem to work either.

**Edit:**
I also tried to set an interval to check for the web3 object every few seconds. But that didn't work either.

**Edit 2:** Since I'm using web3js 1.x I tried the following:

```js
componentDidMount() {

  window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    if (Web3.givenProvider) {
      let web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);
      alert(web3.currentProvider.host);
      console.log(web3.currentProvider);
      web3.eth.getAccounts((err, accts) => {
        if (!err) {
          web3.eth.net.getNetworkType((err, network) => {
            if (!err) {
              this.setState({
                web3,
                isConnected: true,
                network: network,
                user: accts[0]
              });
            } else {
              alert(err);
            }
          });
        } else {
          alert(err);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to get error messages with the `alerts`. Now status responds with `You tried to send "undefined" synchronously. Synchronous requests are not supported, sorry`. I don't get it. This is not a synchronous request?!

Trust also tells me `Error: Trust does not support calling undefined synchronously without a callback parameter to call undefined asynchronously.`.

Answer (score 2):

Trust doesn't support 1.0 beta, no ETA either. I suppose the android/ios bindings they use still haven't been updated.
https://github.com/TrustWallet/trust-web3-provider/issues/58.

Edit: I found the code that explains the supported methods:
https://github.com/TrustWallet/trust-web3-provider/blob/master/src/index.js#L72

Comment: Thanks for answer. How to use those methods in browser side simple Javascript implementation?  I am getting window.web3  object.. but can not call other functions. Any help appreciated.